# WooCommerce custom child products to variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce, custom-fields

I have some variable products (different 3-4 variations) with different prices. I want to add some simple products as child products (show as optional checkbox in front). I don't know how to manage that for adding to the cart.
For example let's assume I have a `cellphone` as main product and when user added it to it's cart it should see 3 sub product (child product) :

- Handsfree (in three type of color)
- Glass guard (in two type of color )
- cell phone shield case ( just black)

as you can understand from above example I wanna to: 
add all of this items as one product (includes `handsfree, glass guard , cellphone case and cellphone itself` ) and calculate it's price .I've read [Add a checkbox on single product pages that adds an additional cost in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500320) and after that I have codes below to adding options in product edit page.

```
//custom product tab to woocommerce edit
function sm_wccpd_custom_product_tabs($tabs)
 {
    $tabs['sm_wcpa_extra_products'] = array(
      'label'  => __('Samanik Extra Products', 'sm-wcpa'),
      'target' => 'sm_wc_extra_products_options',
      'class'  => array('show_if_variable'),
    );
    return $tabs;
  }
  add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'sm_wccpd_custom_product_tabs');
```

and here is tab content

```
function extra_products_options_product_tab_content()


{
    global $post;

    // Note the 'id' attribute needs to match the 'target' parameter set above
    ?>
    <div id='sm_wc_extra_products_options' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'><?php
?>
    <div class='options_group'><?php
  woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
    [
      'id'    => '_has_extra_products',
      'label' => __('has extra products', 'sm-wcpa'),
    ]);
  woocommerce_wp_select(
    [
      'class'             => 'multiselect attribute_values wc-enhanced-select',
      'custom_attributes' => ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'style' => 'width:100% !importan;'],
      'id'                => '_sm_wcpa_product[]',
      'label'             => __('Extra Products to be add here', 'sm-wcpa'),
      'value'             => array_values(json_decode(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_sm_wcpa_product'), true)),
      'options'           => sm_wcpa_get_products_as_options(),//this is function that I pass Products as array like [product_id => product name]
    ]);

  ?></div>

    </div><?php
}
//  add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'extra_products_options_product_tab_content'); // WC 2.5 and below
  add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'extra_products_options_product_tab_content'); // WC 2.6 and up
```

also I can save the data and I think they are not necessary here.

now what I need to do is how to manage this in front. I mean show child products as checkbox, add price to parent price if checked, what about changing variables(those have different prices).

thanks for your patient to read my question.